# What peer-reviewed evidence supports Procatalepsis?

Tags: emotional-intelligence

I copy pasted the transcript of *How to win a negotiation, with former FBI hostage chief Chris Voss*, starting at [3:39](https://youtu.be/tYv44wQYePg?t=219).

> So knowing that fear of loss is probably going
> to drive someone's decision-making more than anything else,
> tactically, I want to diffuse those fears.
> I want to get them out of that fear-based thinking,
> and I want to get them really in a more rational,
> open frame of mind as quickly as I can,
> which is why, tactically and empathy,
> I wanna address their fears first. Well, labeling is the best way to practice tactical empathy:
> In its strictest form, it's just saying, or writing,
> "it seems like, it sounds like, it looks like,"
> putting a label on the dynamic.
> **And science is showing us now, that if we label a negative,
> it diminishes it. [my emphasis]**
> I'll actually say to somebody ahead of time,
> "Look, this is gonna sound really harsh,
> and there's a really good chance
> that when I get done saying what I'm gonna say,
> you're not gonna like me at all."
> And then I'll say what I have to say,
> and they'll say, "Wow, that wasn't that bad."
> So I know I can take a very preemptive approach
> to negative thinking because I know what a barrier it is
> to decision-making in business.

1. What "science" was Chris Voss referring to? Please cite *peer-reviewed* evidence?
2. I'm uncertain if the ["highfalutin term for this is *procatalepsis*"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/138243/what-is-it-called-when-someone-says-something-like-im-not-a-racist-but#comment404707_138254), or [apophasis](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/279369)?

I'm leery of Procatalepsis, because [My unsympathetic reading of the phrase "no offense" is that its user is trying to pre-emptively escape blame for saying something obviously offensive.](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/504981/why-do-people-say-no-offense-when-starting-a-sentence#comment1220833_504981)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chris Voss's statement about science showing that labeling a negative diminishes it likely refers to research in psychology related to emotional regulation and affect labeling. Affect labeling refers to putting feelings into words, which can help people regulate their emotional experiences.

One study, "Putting Feelings into Words: Affect Labeling Disrupts Amygdala Activity to Affective Stimuli" (Hariri et al., 2006) published in the journal Psychological Science, found that labeling emotions can reduce the response of the amygdala, a part of the brain that plays a key role in processing emotional reactions. This implies that affect labeling, such as identifying and naming a fear, can help lessen the intensity of the emotion.

Another study, "Affect Labeling Enhances Exposure Effectiveness for Public Speaking Anxiety" (Niles et al., 2015) published in the journal Behaviour Research and Therapy, found that affect labeling can enhance exposure therapy outcomes for people with public speaking anxiety. This research supports the idea that labeling an emotion can help reduce its intensity and improve coping mechanisms.

As for the rhetorical terms you mentioned, both procatalepsis and apophasis are indeed highfalutin terms for rhetorical strategies, but they refer to different tactics:

Procatalepsis is a figure of speech in which the speaker raises an objection to their own argument and then immediately answers it. By doing so, they hope to strengthen their argument by dealing with possible counter-arguments beforehand.

Apophasis, on the other hand, is a rhetorical device where the speaker or writer brings up a subject by either denying it, or denying that they should talk about it. The effect is to bring the subject up in the minds of the audience without the speaker appearing to have done so.

In the context of the quote from Chris Voss, it could be argued that he's using a form of apophasis when he says "Look, this is gonna sound really harsh, and there's a really good chance that when I get done saying what I'm gonna say, you're not gonna like me at all." He's introducing a negative idea (that the listener might not like him) while seeming to dismiss it or distance himself from it. He then mitigates the impact of his subsequent statement by having already labeled and acknowledged the potential negative reaction.

Comment: Can you please provide a link to the Hariri et al. (2006) paper?  The title and author don't seem to match for me.